# Sending url via smtplib module (text message)

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtplib

My program gets images from the r/memes subreddit. I am trying to figure out how to send the urls of those memes to my iphone via smtplib. I have run intothe error of the text message being blank. Here is my code:

```
import praw
import praw, requests
import smtplib
import time



reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='________',
                 client_secret='______',
                 user_agent='____',
                 username="____",
                 password="_____")

for submission in reddit.subreddit("memes").stream.submissions(skip_existing=True):


server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
server.login('________', '________')
time.sleep(1)
server.sendmail('________', '_______', str(submission.url))
server.quit()
time.sleep(1800)
pass
```

Is this because the url has special characters?, I have tried twilio, but I would like to run this script on python anywhere to keep it active. Thank You!

Ps: I operate on Python3, MacOS.

Comment: have you tried raw strings? Could you elaborate on what is in submission.url/ example.

Comment: Hello: So the praw module looks on the r/memes subreddit for well... memes, it then gets the url from the image(the meme on the subreddit). what I am trying to do is send that collected url to myself (my iphone) since the url is different each time I do not believe I can use raw strings but of course I can always be wrong.                   
Ex: Praw picks up: https://i.redd.it/lnnp0q6wo3951.png (example meme), then I want said url to be sent to my phone number. I have tried this with twilio and it worked fine in my IDE (pycharm) but when run in python anywhere it said "connection refused"

Comment: so basically, the sending works but you receive an empty message on your email?

Comment: Yes exactly that!

Comment: Try doing this `"\n\n\n" + str(submission.url)`, since sometimes the messages gets mistaken as a part of the header, not the body.

Comment: Ok That fixed it!                                                                                                                 
(of course I wish there was a way I could send the actual image and not just the url but thats for another day). Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this `"\n\n\n" + str(submission.url)`, since sometimes the messages gets mistaken as a part of the header, not the body.